# Creating Podfile returns an error message

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to use CocoaPods for first time since I installed it using this command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then I will create the `Podfile` using this command

```
pod init
```

Then I get this error

```
**[!] /usr/bin/git clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master --depth=1
Cloning into 'master'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': SSLRead() return error -9806**
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `pod setup --verbose`

Comment: i usually just do "touch Podfile" and then add it to xcode :)

Comment: thanks @Keith it works create after executing the command pod setup --verbose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is happening on first run of CocoaPods because it is trying to create a local copy of the specs repo. To diagnose what's going wrong in this process you can run

```
pod setup --verbose
```